# Advertise lot of positions using Eddystone with a Raspberry PI

Tags: android, raspberry-pi, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon, eddystone

I want to advertise car positions with Eddystone beacon with a Raspberry PI for Android phones. It is possible to send for example 30 car situation withtin one beacon or I should advertise every situation in different beacons? It is possible to send lot of beacons with one beacon advertiser and changed them in real time?

Any other suggest to share positions collected by raspberry with android phones?  The area is approximately a 70m circle.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To do this at all, the amount of data to be transmitted for each car must be limited, as there is not much space in the advertisement.  Presuming you track the car location in two dimensions, you will need to encode three fields:

- Car identifier
- Position X
- Position Y

The first field can be held with 5 bits to track 64 different cars

The X and Y coordinates will likely need more bits to give you any reasonable precision.  Is 21 bits enough?  This would give you values of 0-2097151 for x and y.

Based on the above, you will need 47 bits of data space in the beacon advertisement, plus extra bits to know it is *your* advertisement vs. that of some other transmitter.

Eddystone-UID by design has 48 bits of data space in the instance identifier.  So this will work.  You can use the namespace identifier to ensure it is your beacon.

On the Raspberry Pi, you can alter the transmitted beacon identifier every 0.5 second, and transmit 40 car positions every 20 seconds. Because the transmitter can be set to go at 10 Hz, it is very likely the Android devices will receive each one, as there will be 5 sent over the air.

If you need updates more often than 20 seconds, you will need more transmitters.